# Account creation errors with Jhipster after altering user service class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

So I've been using Jhipster & spring boot to make a webapp. So, in my JDL i have a User Account Entity and now I know Jhipster also provides a user entity for you, but I'm trying to use my user account entity to add more functionality to the user entity without having to directly edit the code of the user class itself. So what I was trying to do is implement the functionality where a UserAccount entity is created with all the information provided to create the original User entity in JHipster, and I followed these steps that my mate gave me:

Locate the Service Class: Find the service class in your JHipster application that handles the creation of a User entity.
Modify the Service Class: Amend this service class to include an additional step that creates a UserAccount entity whenever a new User is created.
Dependency Injection: Utilize Dependency Injection to inject the repository or service responsible for creating UserAccount entities into the User service class.
Create UserAccount After User: After creating a new User, use the injected repository or service to create a new UserAccount with the same information.

I added these changes to my userservice class and you can see them here where I've added the comments //added this. Here's the code to my class sorry it's formatted like this stack overflow doesn't let me add pastebin links.

`public class UserService {

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

private final UserRepository userRepository;

private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

private final AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;

private final CacheManager cacheManager;

private final UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository; //added this

public UserService(
    UserRepository userRepository,
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
    AuthorityRepository authorityRepository,
    CacheManager cacheManager,
    UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository //added this
) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.authorityRepository = authorityRepository;
    this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    this.userAccountRepository = userAccountRepository; //added this
}

public Optional<User> activateRegistration(String key) {
    log.debug("Activating user for activation key {}", key);
    return userRepository
        .findOneByActivationKey(key)
        .map(user -> {
            // activate given user for the registration key.
            user.setActivated(true);
            user.setActivationKey(null);
            this.clearUserCaches(user);
            log.debug("Activated user: {}", user);
            return user;
        });
}

public Optional<User> completePasswordReset(String newPassword, String key) {
    log.debug("Reset user password for reset key {}", key);
    return userRepository
        .findOneByResetKey(key)
        .filter(user -> user.getResetDate().isAfter(Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)))
        .map(user -> {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
            user.setResetKey(null);
            user.setResetDate(null);
            this.clearUserCaches(user);
            return user;
        });
}

public Optional<User> requestPasswordReset(String mail) {
    return userRepository
        .findOneByEmailIgnoreCase(mail)
        .filter(User::isActivated)
        .map(user -> {
            user.setResetKey(RandomUtil.generateResetKey());
            user.setResetDate(Instant.now());
            this.clearUserCaches(user);
            return user;
        });
}

public User registerUser(AdminUserDTO userDTO, String password) {
    userRepository
        .findOneByLogin(userDTO.getLogin().toLowerCase())
        .ifPresent(existingUser -> {
            boolean removed = removeNonActivatedUser(existingUser);
            if (!removed) {
                throw new UsernameAlreadyUsedException();
            }
        });
    userRepository
        .findOneByEmailIgnoreCase(userDTO.getEmail())
        .ifPresent(existingUser -> {
            boolean removed = removeNonActivatedUser(existingUser);
            if (!removed) {
                throw new EmailAlreadyUsedException();
            }
        });
    User newUser = new User();
    String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    newUser.setLogin(userDTO.getLogin().toLowerCase());
    // new user gets initially a generated password
    newUser.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
    newUser.setFirstName(userDTO.getFirstName());
    newUser.setLastName(userDTO.getLastName());
    if (userDTO.getEmail() != null) {
        newUser.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail().toLowerCase());
    }
    newUser.setImageUrl(userDTO.getImageUrl());
    newUser.setLangKey(userDTO.getLangKey());
    // new user is not active
    newUser.setActivated(false);
    // new user gets registration key
    newUser.setActivationKey(RandomUtil.generateActivationKey());
    Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    authorityRepository.findById(AuthoritiesConstants.USER).ifPresent(authorities::add);
    newUser.setAuthorities(authorities);
    userRepository.save(newUser);
    this.clearUserCaches(newUser);
    log.debug("Created Information for User: {}", newUser);
    return newUser;
}

private boolean removeNonActivatedUser(User existingUser) {
    if (existingUser.isActivated()) {
        return false;
    }
    userRepository.delete(existingUser);
    userRepository.flush();
    this.clearUserCaches(existingUser);
    return true;
}

public User createUser(AdminUserDTO userDTO) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setLogin(userDTO.getLogin().toLowerCase());
    user.setFirstName(userDTO.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(userDTO.getLastName());
    if (userDTO.getEmail() != null) {
        user.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail().toLowerCase());
    }
    user.setImageUrl(userDTO.getImageUrl());
    if (userDTO.getLangKey() == null) {
        user.setLangKey(Constants.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE); // default language
    } else {
        user.setLangKey(userDTO.getLangKey());
    }
    String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(RandomUtil.generatePassword());
    user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
    user.setResetKey(RandomUtil.generateResetKey());
    user.setResetDate(Instant.now());
    user.setActivated(true);
    if (userDTO.getAuthorities() != null) {
        Set<Authority> authorities = userDTO
            .getAuthorities()
            .stream()
            .map(authorityRepository::findById)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
    }


    UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount(); //added this
    userAccount.setDisplayName(userDTO.getFirstName() + " " + userDTO.getLastName()); //added this
    userAccount.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail().toLowerCase()); //added this
    userAccount.setUser(user); // added this

    userRepository.save(user);
    userAccountRepository.save(userAccount); //added this

    this.clearUserCaches(user);
    log.debug("Created Information for User: {}", user);
    return user;
}`
```

I've mostly just edited the constructors and the create user method. Now the code compiles but the error I get is that when I try to create an account it doesn't let me. I can't see what I've done wrong from a logical perspective. Any help would be much appreciated.

(fyi I know I'm missing the imports from my file I did it so the code is easier to read)

- So the app compiles and I can run it off a local machine it's when I create an account I get errors.